# jQuery - same effect, on multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slide

I've been play around with `jQuery` lately and i managed to write a simple code that will move/slide (on Hover) an image away, revealing some data I've hidden behind it.

It's something I wanna use on a portfolio page to show some work.

My problem is, that the script works fine on a single DIV, however, it does not seem to work on the other DIVs that have the same ID i've called in my code.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $('#featured-work-thumbnail').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.front').stop().animate({'top' : '300px'}, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
    }, function(){
        $(this).children('.front').stop().animate({'top' : '0px', 'left' : '0px'}, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is an example of the DIV am using:

```
<div id="featured-work-thumbnail" class="wrap">
    <div class="details">
        <h1>Website Title</h1>
        <p>Website Desc</p>
        <a href="#">Visit Website</a>
    </div>
<img src="images/thumbnails/thumb1.png" class="front" />
</div>
```

When i hover over the image, it slides down, revealing the `class="details"` DIV beneath it. Which is exactly what am after, however as i mentioned. It will only work on a single copy of my DIV.

Thanks in advance for your time, and help.
Much Appreciated

Comment: Make a selection for all divs of class "details" and then apply the function.

Comment: You should NEVER put the same value for an id on more than one div on a page. By definition, IDs are supposed to be unique. Use a class if you want to put something on multiple divs of a similar type, and instead use that in the jQuery selector.

Comment: Thank you, Cliff. That did the trick. I never knew that ID or CLASS can make such difference. Appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#featured-work-thumbnail').hover(function(){
$(this).children('.front').stop().animate({'top' : '300px'}, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
$(this).children('.front').stop().animate({'top' : '0px', 'left' : '0px'}, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
});
```